# Choosing pixel size when projecting raster from geographic to projected coordinate system

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.3, pixel

I have a raster showing animal abundance (straight count) in all of Canada. The raster was created unprojected in GRS 80 with a pixel size of 0.0833 decimal degrees. I was ask to project this raster to Canada Albers Equal Area Conic. I have never seen an unprojected raster before and don't know why it would be created this way. When inputting the raster into ArcGIS 10.3 reproject tool, the default pixel size is set to 8787.96 m. I realize that no one pixel size would be correct because a decimal degree in one part of the country would be a different length than another part.

Is there any standard protocol or guidelines in this situation?

Comment: How are your animal abundance data represented?  Are they counts, proportions, densities, or something else?  It matters when you reproject!

Comment: One set is just pure count and I have another set that is densities.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.